# Get a complete list of dependencies for each item, when initially only one level of child and parent dependencies is specified for each item

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have data structure that looks like this:

```
const items = [
  { id: '1', subItems: ['2', '3'], majorItems: ['4'] },
  { id: '4', subItems: ['1'], majorItems: [] },
  { id: '2', subItems: ['5'], majorItems: ['1'] },
  { id: '5', subItems: [], majorItems: ['2'] },
  { id: '3', subItems: [], majorItems: ['1'] },
]
```

[image: example]

I need to transform this structure into this form:

```
const result = {
  '1': ['2','3','5'],
  '4': ['1','2','3','5'],
  '2': ['5'],
  '5': [],
  '3': []
}
```

Could you help me with finding the optimal algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Share what you have tried so far so we can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive function that performs a DFS traversal, and memoization to avoid doing double work:

```js
function createList(items) {
    let map = new Map(items.map(item => [item.id, item.subItems]));
    let memo = new Map;

    function recur(id, tab="") {
        let result = memo.get(id);
        if (!result) {
            result = [...map.get(id)];
            memo.set(id, result = [...result, ...result.flatMap(recur)]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    return Object.fromEntries(items.map(({id}) => [id, recur(id)]));
}

// demo
const items = [
  { id: '1', subItems: ['2', '3'], majorItems: ['4'] },
  { id: '4', subItems: ['1'], majorItems: [] },
  { id: '2', subItems: ['5'], majorItems: ['1'] },
  { id: '5', subItems: [], majorItems: ['2'] },
  { id: '3', subItems: [], majorItems: ['1'] },
];

console.log(createList(items));
```

Note that the keys of the result object are iterated/displayed in their numerical order. This is ECMAScript specified behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create one object so you can use it as lookup table, then you create nested structure by replacing ids with actual objects. And then you just go through nested structure and return those children ids.

```js
const items = [
  { id: '1', subItems: ['2', '3'], majorItems: ['4'] },
  { id: '4', subItems: ['1'], majorItems: [] },
  { id: '2', subItems: ['5'], majorItems: ['1'] },
  { id: '5', subItems: [], majorItems: ['2'] },
  { id: '3', subItems: [], majorItems: ['1'] },
]

const map = {},result = {}
items.forEach(e => map[e.id] = e)

items.forEach(item => {
  item.subItems.forEach((id, i) => {
    item.subItems[i] = map[id]
  })
})

Object.entries(map).forEach(([k, v]) => {
  result[k] = (function getIds(data) {
    return data.reduce((r, e) => {
      return r.concat(e.id, getIds(e.subItems))
    }, [])
  })(v.subItems)
})

console.log(result)
```